# SQL Oracle exctrac value from XML unordered Collection

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, extract

I have a clob with XML like this:

```
<Data>  
 <Email_List>
      <Email>
         <EmailPrimaryFlag>Y</EmailPrimaryFlag>
         <EmailAddress>test@test.it</EmailAddress>
      </Email>
      <Email>
         <EmailPrimaryFlag>N</EmailPrimaryFlag>
         <EmailAddress>test2@test2.it</EmailAddress>
      </Email>
      <Email>
         <EmailPrimaryFlag>N</EmailPrimaryFlag>
         <EmailAddress>test3@test3.it</EmailAddress>
      </Email>
   </Email_List>
   <User>Name_User</User>
   <City>City_test</City>
</Data>
```

I need to do an extract only for PrimaryFlag=Y

Usually i do something like this:

```
select
extract(xmltype(PAYLOAD),'//*:User/text()').getStringVal() as User,
extract(xmltype(PAYLOAD),'//*:City/text()').getStringVal() as City,
```

but i don't know how i can extract for mail with PrimaryFlag=Y

Special Thanks

Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using EXRACT() as it is deprecated.

```
with t (payload) as (
select to_clob('<Data>  
 <Email_List>
      <Email>
         <EmailPrimaryFlag>Y</EmailPrimaryFlag>
         <EmailAddress>test@test.it</EmailAddress>
      </Email>
      <Email>
         <EmailPrimaryFlag>N</EmailPrimaryFlag>
         <EmailAddress>test2@test2.it</EmailAddress>
      </Email>
      <Email>
         <EmailPrimaryFlag>N</EmailPrimaryFlag>
         <EmailAddress>test3@test3.it</EmailAddress>
      </Email>
   </Email_List>
   <User>Name_User</User>
   <City>City_test</City>
</Data>') from dual)
select x.* from t, xmltable(
'/Data'
passing xmltype(payload)
columns
 primary_email varchar2(60) path 'Email_List/Email/EmailAddress[../EmailPrimaryFlag = "Y"]',
 username varchar2(60)      path 'User',
 city varchar2(60)          path 'City'
)x;

PRIMARY_EMAIL                                                  USERNAME                                                       CITY                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------   ------------------------------------------------------------   ------------------------------------------------------------
test@test.it                                                   Name_User                                                      City_test
```

Comment: Slkrasnodar, Though your code works perfect fine, but EXTRACT works perfectly fine.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions068.htm#SQLRF00640

Comment: The documentation says to use `xmlquery`. The reason for using `xmltable` instead of  `xmlquery` is to get 3 values in one parse.

Comment: I don't know that. Thank you so much for sharing such wonderful knowledge. I will surely use it for my further work process.